# How do I iterate over a dynamic keyed object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a hashed object where the keys are added dynamically through user selections.

I want to iterate over it and extract the values similar to the way I would do if it was simply an array: `selections.map(cart => /*do stuff*/)`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: get the keys to iterate over then get the value of the keys.

Comment: Iterate over the keys and access the values that way? edit: Beaten by @LoïcFaure-Lacroix aha

Comment: Did you try `for (var key in object) { ... }`?

Comment: Or in ES5 I think you can use `Object.keys(yourObject)` to get an array of all the object's keys...

Comment: `Object.values` always worth a mention: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The **`Object.keys()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
var array = Object.keys(selections).map(k => selections[k]);
// get all values from the object
```

Comment: Does it return a new array or mutates the original?

Comment: `Object.keys` returns a new array. it does not mutate the object.